# How to NOT add the description of a table in the "List of table"

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Currently I'm writing the table description in \caption{Here I write the description}. The problem is that I also write the title within the \caption. This causes the List of tables to both include the title and description (see picture). [image]

I'm sure there are ways of splitting the title and the description so the list of table /list of figures gets it right, i.e. only includes the title. Maybe there is a way to make the title to be more prominent compared to the description in the table itself as well.

Im using this code for the table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\renewcommand\thetable{Appendix. A1}
    \captionsetup{width=16cm}
  \caption{This is the Title of the table. This is some text that are not supposed to be added in the "List of tables", but only together with the table.
} 
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    & & \thead{Obs.} & \thead{Mean} & \thead{Median} & \thead{Std.dev} & \thead{p-value\\(means)} & \thead{p-value\\(medians)}
    \\\midrule
    \hline \\[-2.3ex] 
Log(amount issued) & Green bond & $25$ & $20.009$ & $20.030$ & $0.620$ & 0.207 & 0.009
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\caption[This is the Title of the table]{This is the Title of the table. This is some text that are not supposed to be added in the "List of tables", but only together with the table.
} `

Comment: unrelated but don't do this `\hline \\[-2.3ex] ` here should be no `\\ ` afer `\hline`.